# Using addthis on a high traffic website

Tags: social-media, addthis, sharing

Would custom social sharing buttons work better than the bulky addthis widget on a highly trafficked website (100mil pageviews/day)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, mainly because most large social network's code is delivered from a powerful CDN.

I would advise loading the scripts at the foot of your page as this will mitigate the script's effect on your overall page load time and user experience.

Comment: well addthis' js is loaded from their CDN which is pretty good.

Comment: @surpr not nearly as good as the one's the big social networks use.

Comment: Ya I figured.. if we could self host the addthis js on our CDN it would be worth it.

Comment: @surpr there really isn't anything preventing you from doing that, you could script the update process so you get a new copy on to your CDN once a day.

Comment: Add this use Akamai for their CDN, so you'd be hard pushed to get faster than that. The only benefit of hosting it on your own domain would be to limit DNS lookups on your page.

Comment: Actually, that can slow down a site because browsers limit the number of parallel requests to a single domain. Even Google's performance analysis tool recommends to spread resources across domain names.